# Error when passing an object by reference 

Tags: c++, qt, reference

So I have a problem....

I've a method
void MainWindow::loadItems(const ArticleStore& store)
{
}

that I try to call like this inside the MainWindow class
    ArticleStore store();
    loadItems(store)

And I get this error 
mainwindow.cpp:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘MainWindow::loadItems(ArticleStore (&)())’ 
mainwindow.h:19: note: candidates are: void MainWindow::loadItems(const ArticleStore&)

ArticleStore definition:
class ArticleStore
{
public:
    ArticleStore();
};

So the question is what went wrong?

Comment: could you post some source-code as well? It looks like you messed something up in the call.

Comment: do you have multiple definitions of ArticleStore perhaps?

Comment: Please do not attempt to format your code using HTML tags. Use the 1010 button above the editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because

```
ArticleStore store();
```

is interpreted by the compiler as a function declaration.
That's explain why compiler is looking for `‘MainWindow::loadItems(ArticleStore (&)())’` 
You must write instead:

```
Article store; // With no parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArticleStore store; loadItems(store);
```

Notice the lack of brackets after the name. The compiler is mistaking your version as a function prototype for a function called store, taking no arguments and returning an `ArticleStore` instance. Then you pass this function pointer to the next function which doesn't work.